# Why my sp deadlocked in a transaction?

Tags: t-sql, deadlock

This is what the sp does:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL Serializable
begin transaction 
IF EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Portfolio WHERE RawMessageID = @RawMessageID)
begin
----do some cleaning job like delete the portfolio, or something
end

insert into Portfolio
select @a,@b,@c,@d

commit
```

Randomly, I see deadlock happen and this deadlock graph showing the detail.

So it has to be that one instance of the call hold the shared lock from the select statement and asking for an null resource lock. Another instance holds the null resource lock and asks for shared lock.

Is my guess right? I was trying to write an simplified version to demo this, but never can trigger this deadlock.

Can someone help?
[image]

Comment: Do you really need Serializable isolation level? it's a very strict level that's not always needed.

Comment: I am more interested in why this will be a problem in Serializable isolation.

Comment: Hard to guess if you don't show the complete code of the sprocs deadlocking...

Comment: most likely the select query is s-s locking a non-cluster index and then are asking for a insert lock on primary key. Then the insert statement has the primary key and waits the s-s locking to be released. I tried to create some demo, but turned out to be difficult.